# How can i terminate program when target value equal to the res value in my program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,res,target=10,arr[5] = {5,3,7,1,8};

for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        res = arr[i]+arr[j];
        printf("%d\n",res);
        if(res == target)
        {
            printf("success\n");
            break;

        }
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

I want to terminate this program when the target value equals to the res value.break doesn't work.how can i solve this problem.???

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qvJz.png)

Answer (score 0):

So you can use return instead of break:

```
    if(res == target)
    {
        printf("success\n");
        return 0;  //<-- instead of break
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir. I have another question.that i want to print the index value of my array in if statement instead of success message..how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

To terminate your program, change

```
printf("success\n");
            break;
```

To

```
printf("success\n");
            return 0;
```

The `return 0` will stop the program.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have used break to exit from the current loop have you tried **exit(1)**;

Answer (score 0):

Exit function is used to terminate the execution of program in C Language

Syntax:

> exit(0);

Find the link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_exit.htm)